# Is it possible to check list of multicasts groups when there're no joined users?

Tags: linux, multicast, icmp, igmp

I can get a list of joined multicasts using `netstat -g`, but is it possible to get list of available (not joined) multicasts. Does Linux kernel keep track of incoming group specific IGMP/MLD queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to check list of multicasts groups when there're no joined users?
>   In group is empty e.g. in your network no subscribers - no multicast traffic also.
>
> but is it possible to get list of available (not joined) multicasts.
>   Same, no recipients no traffic
>
> Does Linux kernel keep track of incoming group specific IGMP/MLD queries?
>   A specific kernel that has IGMP Snooping enabled or another IGMP feature.

Take a look at smcroute, mrouted for multicast traffic routing some of these services might have logging feature, so you will be able to track multicast traffic.